# Why does the output read "null" when I am trying to do Java Binary I/O?

Tags: java, java-io

I am learning how to perform Java Binary Input/Output. So before starting my full assignment, I just wanted to make sure I knew how to perform basic I/O. I can do Text I/O, but I keep having problems with Binary I/O. My code simply writes a couple things to a binary file. And then more code simply reads the binary file and prints its data.

This is the code that writes data to the binary file. Don't worry about exactly what's written to the file. I just put random things.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Write
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DataOutputStream writer = null;
                              
        try
        {
            writer = new DataOutputStream(
                     new BufferedOutputStream(
                     new FileOutputStream("writer.dat")));
                 
            writer.writeInt(8);
            writer.writeChars("Monkey       ");
            writer.writeChars("Bottled Water");
            writer.writeChars("Truth        ");
            writer.writeDouble(29.99);
        
            writer.close();
        }
    
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that reads the data from the binary file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Read
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DataInputStream reader = null;
        int integ = 0;
        String [] names = new String[3];
        double win = 0;
    
        try
        {
            reader = new DataInputStream(
                     new BufferedInputStream(
                     new FileInputStream("writer.dat")));
                  
            integ = reader.readInt();
        
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
            {
                for ( int j = 0 ; j < 13 ; j++ )
                {
                    names[i] += reader.readChar();
                }
            }
        
            win = reader.readDouble();
        
            reader.close();
        }
    
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    
        System.out.println(integ);
    
        for ( int e = 0 ; e < 3 ; e++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[e]);
        }
    
        System.out.println(win);
    }
}
```

[This is the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCQb8.png)

Can someone explain why it says null in front of the words?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `names` array declaration :

```
String [] names = new String[3];
```

with

```
String [] names = {"","",""};
```

or

```
String [] names = new String[3];
names[0] = "";
names[1] = "";
names[2] = "";
```

You have `null` at the beginning of the words because the individual values of the array `names` are `null` (you didn't initialize them).

So in your loop when `i=0, j=0`, the instruction `names[i] += reader.readChar();` will be equivalent to :

```
names[0] += reader.readChar();
```

which is equivalent to :

```
names[0] = names[0] + reader.readChar();
```

but because the `names` array values are not initialized, `names[0]` is equal to null.

So the previous expression is equivalent :

```
names[0] = null + reader.readChar();
```

So `names[0]` is now equal to `nullM` in the first iteration of the loop and will be `nullMonkey` at the end.